# How to resolve error, "The name 'myClass' does not exist in the current context" for unit test?

Tags: c#

I am writing a unit test for a small console application I'm building, however, the unit test does not recognize the class I'm referring to from the main program.

Unit test

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Assert = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert;
using System;
using MyApp;

namespace MyTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SampleTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFunction()
        {
            // Arrange
            string firstName = "John";
            string lastName = "Smith";
            string expectedOutput = "My name is John Smith";

            // Act
            string actualOutput = SampleClass.SampleString(name, age);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, actualOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Main application

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static class SampleClass
        {
            public static string SampleString(string firstName, string lastName)
            {
                // Code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both projects are in the same solution but I am getting the error "The name 'SampleClass' does not exist in the current context" despite the `using MyApp;` statement at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change this line to properly qualify the class:

```
string actualOutput = Program.SampleClass.SampleString(name, age);
```

or pull the class out of `Program`:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {

    } //Program ends here

    public static class SampleClass
    {
        public static string SampleString(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            //Code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that leaving `SampleClass` in the `Program` class is highly inadvisable, and is pretty counterintuitive to use.

Comment: @Dortimer: While I agree with you, I tend not to comment on the design overall as it tends to be opinionated. I usually limit myself to answering the question at hand. There is more than one thing I would comment on, such as the use of `static`.. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I pulled the function out of the program and it solved the issue. I've extremely new to C# (less than one week in) so forgive me for any odd mistakes like that. If there was anything else that seems off, please let me know. Now, on to the next bug :)

Comment: @VirtuallyHere: No reason to apologize. We've all been there. I would recommend you read a bit about namespaces. Good luck! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/

Comment: @JuanR that's a fair point. But I think if it's solving the problem and making extra suggestions it seems alright. When you get people doing the whole "I don't like the way you did it, so I did it a totally different way." type of opinionated answers, then it's a problem.